# Rails production delete link making get (show) request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When running Rails in development mode and I click a delete link like this:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", scenario_path(@scenario), method: :delete %>
```

It deletes the record as expected.

However when I run the same code in production it makes a request to the show page and doesn’t delete the record.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails uses `rails-ujs` to submit a form to the server when the link is pressed. This is because links are always GET requests and rails requires a DELETE request to delete a record.

So if you have removed `//= require rails-ujs` from your `application.js` it won’t be loaded and requests will be GET instead of DELETE. Or if on an older version of Rails `//= require jquery_ujs`

This was what was causing the issue for me. So when I added `rails-ujs` it started working again. You can confirm this by disabling JS on your app and you will see that DELETE requests won’t work anymore. An alternative solution to adding `rails-ujs` is to use form buttons instead of links as described here: https://www.viget.com/articles/delete-in-rails-without-jquery-and-ujs/

```
<%= button_to "Delete", post_comment_path(@post, comment), method: :delete %>
```